# Woocommerce REST API conditional JSON

Tags: php, json, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I'm using Woocommerce REST API V3 and I want to get a custom JSON callback that is based on a specific element's meta_data (has badge / doesn't have).

If the element has `id:14425` - return 1 (it has a badge).

If the element has `id:Select badge` - return 0 (doesn't have).

This is how metadata looks (I printed it on page just to see the values structure):

`[my_product_badge] => Array ( [0] => a:1:{s:2:"id";s:5:"14425";}`

Code in `wc-api-products.php` file (I deleted most of unrelated piece of codes to make it easier to read) :

```
    private function get_product_data( $product ) {
    $prices_precision = wc_get_price_decimals();
    return array(
        'has_badge' => metadata_exists( 'post', $product->id, 'my_product_badge' ) ? (int) get_post_meta( $product->id, 'my_product_badge', ['id'] && is_numeric , true ) : 0,
    );
}</code>
```

The results I get back in JSON are not based on the rule of `is numeric`

Any ideas?

Comment: @Ehsan thanks, I'm new here :)

Comment: @Ehsan
The results i get back in JSON are not based on the rule of 'is numeric'

Comment: @Ehsan Thanks for the tips :)